# Rabbithole/Neo4j does not really work

Tags: neo4j

I made some modifications of rabbithole projet for Neo4j console .
Indeed, I took another database and everything seems to be perfect, but when I click on the button "Run" for the first time, Neo4j doesn't execute the Cypher query and there are no red nodes (nodes result). When I click the second time on "Run", it works .. I don't know why when clicking the first time on "Run", Neo4j does not execute the query .. Please Help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce this. I've checked out rabbithole and run `mvn -DskipTests=true install exec:java`. The 'Run' buttons works the very first time for me, both in Chrome and Firefox.

Please do provide exact steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you Mr Aarmbruster, but when I tried this for the very first time, it works, but after that it does not work any more .. I don't know if it is a problem of transaction or TIMEOUT .. I don't know